# Normalize .ogg audio files with the command line

Tags: command-line, sound, ogg-vorbis

I'm trying to normalize (and or compress) around 100 .ogg files which have audio level really too low.

I know that by hand I can use Audacity ... but that will be too much clicks!
Instead I was looking for a tool which can be used in a small script (or with --recursive).

Just tried to look in `man oggenc`, `man ffmpeg`, with no success yet...

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you include "compress" in your question? Could you add a couple of lines to your question or answer to clarify that?

Comment: And is there any significant quality degradation?

Comment: @vasa1: In my tests I found that compression would give better dynamic to the sound, mainly for those who are mainly low level and with one peak. I finally adjusted (with Audacity) the 3 files with those special peaks and run the normalization on all the files. Since the original file was really low, I added `-a -15dBFS`. With that option, I don't hear quality degradation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I've found the package `normalize-audio` which provides the tool `normalize-ogg`.
So I just had to run :

```
for audio_file in *.ogg; do
    normalize-ogg $audio_file;
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Vorbisgain will do the trick, the pendent of mp3gain

```
vorbisgain *.ogg
```

Comment: vorbisgain -a *.ogg will treat all the files as an album